# Perform INSERT or UPDATE with the same stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm writing a personal application to handle my railroad time slip tickets.  I have a lot of the application already programmed.  A quick rundown of what the application does....

1. Get tickets from my email box and parses the HTML into class objects
2. INSERTS that ticket into an SQL database

What I ran into is, my "Additional Pay" can change after the payroll department reviews the possible additional pay I may get.  When I sent myself a new ticket, the only thing that will change is that "Additional Pay".

I would like to put all the logic to check for an existing ticket and either INSERT or UPDATE within SQL rather than my C# application.

I've created a test database and a simple console application that reproduces the issue I'm having, just to make pasting "all" the code here simple.

Here's my table in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tickets]
(
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [TicketNumber] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [StraightTime] [money] NULL,
   [OverTime] [money] NULL,
   [AdditionalPay] [money] NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Tickets] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here's my `INSERT` that does work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTickets_Insert]
    @TicketNumber nchar(10),
    @StraightTime money,
    @OverTime money,
    @AdditionalPay money,
    @id int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (TicketNumber, StraightTime, OverTime, AdditionalPay)
    VALUES (@TicketNumber, @StraightTime, @OverTime, @AdditionalPay);

    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Here's my C# console application

```
using Dapper;
using System.Data;

Console.WriteLine("Adding ticket to database using stored procedure");

using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestSQL;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    TicketModel ticket = new TicketModel();
    ticket.TicketNumber = "MC1234";
    ticket.StraightTime = (decimal)234.76;
    ticket.OverTime = (decimal)64.21;
    ticket.AdditionalPay = (decimal)200.12;

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@TicketNumber", ticket.TicketNumber);
    p.Add("@StraightTime", ticket.StraightTime);
    p.Add("@OverTime", ticket.OverTime);
    p.Add("@AdditionalPay", ticket.AdditionalPay);
    p.Add("@id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    connection.Execute("dbo.spTickets_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    ticket.id = p.Get<int>("@id");
}

public class TicketModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? StraightTime { get; set; }
    public decimal? OverTime { get; set; }
    public decimal? AdditionalPay { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the new stored procedure I'm trying to get working

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTickets_InsertUpdate]
    @TicketNumber nchar(10),
    @StraightTime money,
    @OverTime money,
    @AdditionalPay money,
    @id int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tickets WHERE TicketNumber = @TicketNumber)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Tickets
        SET AdditionalPay = @AdditionalPay
        WHERE TicketNumber = @TicketNumber;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Tickets (TicketNumber, StraightTime, OverTime, AdditionalPay)
        VALUES (@TicketNumber, @StraightTime, @OverTime, @AdditionalPay);

        SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
END
```

I change `ticket.AdditionalPay` to another value, and change `dbo.spTickets_Insert` to `dbo.spTickets_InsertUpdate` in my console application to test the UPDATE.

When I do that, I get this error:

> System.ApplicationException: 'Attempting to cast a DBNull to a non nullable type!  Note that out/return parameters will not have updated values until the data stream completes (after the 'foreach' for Query(..., buffered: false), or after the GridReader has been disposed for QueryMultiple)'

I THINK I know that this is because I have that `OUTPUT` parameter in my stored procedure. I have spent a few hours Googling how to fix this.  I've looked at `OUTPUT Inserted.TicketNumber`, and several variations of that.

I'm hoping it's just a syntax thing that I'm not aware of. I am learning many SQL items, stored procedures being one of them, with this project.

I know I can do this check in my C# code and just call either an INSERT or UPDATE stored procedure, but I'd like to combine them and just let SQL handle it if possible.

Thanks!

I've tried using the UPDATE statements OUTPUT parameter with no luck

Comment: Your "update" here will not create a new record, hence you return no value from scope_identity(). But your C# logic expects a value. You will have to decide how to handle that. As it is this is simply the problem you have - what do you want Update to return, since it can't return a scope_identity() value. To put this another way, in your ELSE clause (for insert) you have a select query: `SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();`. But in the IF clause (for update) you have no select query. This mismatch is your problem I think.

Comment: You might want to read about [this upsert antipattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Correct, this is the problem I'm having.  Dapper in my C# application is expecting @id as the output variable.  I'm able to provide that in my INSERT.  I don't know if I can do that in my UPDATE.  Is it possible to send the "id" of the row UPDATEd?  If so, what would that syntax look like?

Comment: I read through the link @Stu provided and the information there made sense, so I created a new stored procedure.  It works as expected in SQL Management Studio, but I'm still getting the same error through C# code, the DBNull error.  I'm not sure how to post the new stored procedure though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get a resolution to this topic....

I was pretty sure I didn't use the "id" in my C# code, so I changed it a bit to not return the SCOPE_IDENTITY() on my INSERT, which meant I didn't need to figure out how to return the "id" on my UPDATE.  I would still be interested if it's possible to do, but I got my stored procedure working.

Comment: 100% it's possible to do,. But you need to decide what id to return. It makes complete sense that you return the ID of the record you just updated. This is trivial to get.

Comment: If you post the actual code your'e using in the answer (to help others infuture) I could suggest a change